# Qadhi decision to divorce a couple after abuse

Tags: talaq, husband-wife, wife, violence

My question is this,

In the case where according to the schools of fiqh, a woman can ask the Qadi (Islamic judge) to divorce her husband even against his decision in the case of her husband's abuse, excessive bad behavior or violence and injustice, how can the wife prove to the husband all this since it is a private matter?

Are there any records from Muslim countries in the history of the Muslim world that explain these details? What if the husband denies the facts?

Comment: As for the last part of your question there will certainly be records because these are the basis for rulings. However it would be a tough task to find some.

Comment: The sources of evidence are universal such as confession, testimony, circumstantial evidence etc. The Qadi would inquire from neighbors and arbitrators, if necessary he would make the husband keep the wife among neighbors who can keep an eye on them and inform the Qadi.

Comment: @UmH

when you say: he asks the husband to keep the wife among the neighbors who can keep an eye on them.

What do you mean by that? I did not understand